# What's the ideal tag to use when I want to apply a css style to a block of text?

Tags: html, css

To style text, I typically use one of the following:

```
<span class="header">...</span>
<div class="header">...</div>
<p class="header">...</p>
<label class="header">...</label>
```

But does it actually matter which tag I use for applying a css style to a block of text?

Usually I use `<div>` for everything that should be in a single block (like headers or footnotes), or `<span>` for everything inline (like emphasized text in a paragraph), however I but recently found myself using a `<div>` tag to style the text `*Required`, which I thought seemed a bit silly since it's a single word, and I started wondering if this was the "correct" way of doing things, or if one tag was better than another to use for simple text styling like this.

Is there some kind of standard about which tag to use when I want to apply a css class to a block of text? And if so, what factors determine which tag to use and when?

Comment: What do you mean by styling text? Text can serve a variety of purposes, and these purposes are determined - first and foremost - by HTML elements, which have various semantics associated with them. Styling them comes secondary.

Comment: Perhaps take a look at W3C docs.

Comment: The W3C describes how each of those elements should be used.

Comment: please check the new tags like **<section>**, **<header>** ,**<footer>** etc. in **HTML5**

Comment: @BoltClock I made some minor edits to my question to try and clarify. There are many times when I want to apply a css class to a block of text, and I am wondering if it matters which tag I use to apply the css style to a block of text, and if so then in which situations should I use each of the 4 tags I listed.

Comment: Styles are meant to be semantically agnostic.  If you want a paragraph to look like a pony or a list to look like a turnip, you are perfectly free to do so.  Choose the tag that has the appropriate semantic meaning for the content, then choose the styling.

Comment: In the HTML4 days the common convention for choosing between `<div>` and `<span>` was that `<div>` was more appropriate for block elements whereas `<span>` was more appropriate for inline elements.

Comment: Related: [Why would one bother marking up properly and semantically?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/164988/why-would-one-bother-marking-up-properly-and-semantically)

Answer (score 8):

Everyone of the tags you quoted has a [semantic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_Web) value.

For example, `<p>` denotes a text paragraph, `<label>` represents a block of text used to annotate an input.
Also a  `<div>` is useful to separate a page in logical sections (divisions, hence the name), not necessarily text only, while a `<span>` is usually used to denote a section of inline text for specific styling (even though a span can be made to be displayed as a block-level element if necessary).

While you are not required to follow the semantics standard, these are helpful when the page needs to be interpreted in a non-visual way, for example by a search engine crawler, that does not "see" the page with human eyes, and needs to know roughly how the page is organized.

Comment: Sooooo... it's not necessarily a good idea to be using the `<div>` tag everywhere for applying different styles to different blocks of text? I hate using `p` because I'm always having to remember to adjust the top and bottom margins to fit the specs I was given, and `label` does't seem appropriate unless I'm making a Label for a specific control. And `span` doesn't work very well outside of inline elements because you can't adjust the right and left spacing of it.

Comment: well yeah, just imagine if you used <divs> to represent section titles and sub-section titles with different styling. Everyone of them would have the same 'value' for the parser even with different classes, while there are elements like h1, h2, h3 that can allow to automatically generate an table of contents from the page without needing to know anything else.

Comment: You make a good point about parsing the non-visual page. I guess I should just use a [css reset stylesheet](http://stackoverflow.com/q/116754/302677) to remove all default styles, and use the correct tags for the correct occasion.

Comment: That's what I usually do when I create a website from scratch. No style at all as long as I don't know what information I want to display, then CSS reset, and finally, page styling for the eye-candy :)

Answer (score 1):

Review the semantic definitions for each type of element you have there: http://w3schools.com/tags/default.asp

While `span` and `div` are semantically neutral, they may be better presented with a class or descriptor that helps to provide meaning to the user and the browser. Additionally, you may be able to use a higher-level block or inline element to provide styling via CSS as opposed to inserting additional elements strictly for the sake of display.

This is one area as well where HTML5 provides some advantages, defining new elements like `article`, `section`, `aside`, `figure`, `header`, `hgroup`, `nav`, `footer`, `details` and `summary`. Each of those element types and their standard usage and assumed meanings in the above link as well.

Markup is not an exact science, but putting some extra thought into the elements used and their implied meanings will help to not only structure your code better, but also give you more options when it comes to CSS selectors.

Answer (score 0):

```
<span class="header">...</span>
```

Is perfect for inline text modifying.

```
<div class="header">...</div>
```

Is usually used for blocks, but yeah also a block with text is a block.

```
<p class="header">...</p>
```

This is for paragraphs. Also they default to have some extra margin under it.

```
<label class="header">...</label>
```

Is only used in context of form elements

You **can** use of all them for everything, you also can make the span to appear as block element, but you cant be sure this would appear the same in all browsers. And as SirDarius already mentioned it is important for non visual ways

Answer (score -2):

*"Everyone of the tags you quoted has a semantic value. For example, `<p>` denotes a paragraph, `<label>` represents a block of text used to annotate an input."*

Sir Darius is absolutely correct. The tags you are using should reflect what they describe.

If you want to know specifically about `<div>`'s and `<span>`'s than `<div>`'s are used for for group block elements usually used to format with css. A `<span>` is used for inline elements (ex. styling one word in a sentence).

Refer [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/) for more information on all tags.